# how to replace the dictionary key with the available key in the list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.6

I have a list of lists with names and their related uids like this:

```
 aList = [['x', 'uid1'], ['y', 'uid2'], ['z', 'uid3']]
```

I have a dict like this:

```
 aDict = {'x': {'a':1}, 'y':{'a':2}, 'z':{'a':7}}
```

Now how can I replace with keys in aDict with the related uids in aList.
Output should be

```
  aDict = {'uid1':{'a':1}, 'uid2':{'a':2}, 'uid3':{'a':7}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (iterating `aList`)

```
>>> {v: aDict[k] for k, v in aList}
{'uid2': {'a': 2}, 'uid3': {'a': 7}, 'uid1': {'a': 1}}
```

**UPDATE**

In case you can't use dict comprehension, use [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) with [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> dict((v, aDict[k]) for k, v in aList)
{'uid2': {'a': 2}, 'uid3': {'a': 7}, 'uid1': {'a': 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert the `aList` to a dictionary like this

```
aList_dict = dict(aList)
```

And then using dictionary comprehension you can construct the new dictionary like this

```
print {aList_dict.get(k, k):aDict[k] for k in aDict}
# {'uid2': {'a': 2}, 'uid3': {'a': 7}, 'uid1': {'a': 1}}
```

`aList_dict.get(k, k)` means, if `k` is found return the value corresponding to it, otherwise return `k` itself.

**Note:** This method will work even when few keys are not there in the `alist`, as it will take the current key itself as the default value, if a matching key is not found.

**Edit:** As you are using Python 2.6 and [dictionary comprehensions were not backported to 2.6 from 3.1](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features), you can use

```
aList_dict = dict(aList)
print dict((aList_dict.get(k, k), aDict[k]) for k in aDict)
```

Comment: well this is having some issues in python 2.6. It says invalid syntax at 'for'

Comment: @user2936254 Please check the edit part in my answer.

Comment: it says NameError: global name 'aList_dict' is not defined

Comment: @user2936254 Please check now.

Comment: I have tried that but it still gives me a NameError

Comment: @user2936254 Can you please post the code which you used?

Comment: In [44]: aList = [['x', 'uid1'], ['y', 'uid2'], ['z', 'uid3']]

In [45]: aList_dict = dict(aList)

In [46]: aDict = {'x': {'a':1}, 'y':{'a':2}, 'z':{'a':7}}

In [47]: print dict((aList_dict.get(k, k), aDict[k]) for k in aDict)

NameError: global name 'aList_dict' is not defined

Comment: @user2936254 The code works fine on my machine and [here](http://ideone.com/kxfHdf) as well. Please check.

Comment: I am using 2.6.6 in particular does it effect?

Comment: @user2936254 Nope. Why don't you restart the console and try?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48382/discussion-between-thefourtheye-and-user2936254)

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 print dict((aList_dict.get(k, k), aDict[k]) for k in aDict)

/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <genexpr>((k,))
----> 1 print dict((aList_dict.get(k, k), aDict[k]) for k in aDict)

NameError: global name 'aList_dict' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the `aList` and get the values from the `aDict`. Copy to result dictionary with `value` as the key.

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for key, value in aList:
...     result[value] = aDict[key]
...     
... 
>>> 
>>> result
{'uid2': {'a': 2}, 'uid3': {'a': 7}, 'uid1': {'a': 1}}
```